# Failing to receive NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreInitialSyncChange

Tags: ios, notifications, key-value, icloud

I have a iPhone/iPad App written in Objective-C.

My App shares data between multiple devices via the iCloud using the Key-Value Storage data model.  This logic has all worked now for literally years.

Yesterday, I cleared my App from my iPhone A, I reinstalled the App onto iPhone A and then I enabled iCloud Sharing on iPhone A.

After enabling iCloud data, as expected, a full copy of my most recent data downloaded onto iPhone A from the iCloud.  Everything looked good.

But later, when I modified the data on iPhone A and attempted to share it with the other devices via iCloud, I got an error message.

The error message warned me that until I had received an InitialSyncChange notification from iCloud, it was unwise for me to propagate the data on iPhone A through the iCloud and onto my other devices.

Long ago, when I wrote this iCloud code, I had set it up so that it would refuse to send data out to the iCloud unless it had previously set a flag indicating that it had seen an incoming InitialSyncChange notification.

But what puzzled me here was that I had seen a copy of my most recent shared data downloaded onto iPhone A from the iCloud after I had enabled iCloud sharing.

When I looked into this and repeated the situation several times, I discovered that when the initial copies of my shared iCloud data were arriving on iPhone A, they were arriving with StoreServerChange notifications and not with InitialSyncChange notifications.

I have no idea why this has changed.  Has anyone else seen something similar?

I have an obvious and easy fix for the problem but, in truth, I really hate applying fixes when I don't fully understand why things have changed.

My fix, if you are curious, would be to change how I set the flag that records if I've seen an incoming InitialSyncChange notification.

Now I will set it when I've seen either a InitialSyncChange notification or StoreServerChange notification.

Either notification 'proves' that I've got a valid copy of the shared data.  And if as the flag is not set, then the existing logic prevents the App from sending out bogus data and messing with the valid shared data.

Any thoughts or trouble-shooting advice would be appreciated.

Comment: So, I'm thinking something has changed recently with iOS.  I don't clear my devices and reload them frequently but I'm sure I would have done a clear and reload within the last two months and at that time, I had no issues.

Comment: More on this issue. I have four devices I used for testing here. - An iPhone 6+ running iOS 12.5.5 over SDK build 15.5.0 - An iPhone XR running iOS 15.4.1 over SDK build 15.5.0 - An iPhone SE running iOS 15.5 over SDK build 15.5.0 and an iPad Air gen3 running iOS 15.5 over SDK build 15.5.0.

The iPhone 6+ behaves as I expect but the others do not.  All are running identical copies of my App.

Comment: Final comment unless I get new input.  I've thoroughly reviewed how I'm doing keyValue sharing via the iCloud and I believe the approach is correct.  No idea why I'm no longer getting InitialSyncChange notifications.  But, I've made the fix I mentioned and it seems to work.